# Take raw_input and make a txt.file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Question, is there a way to take raw_input from a user and create a text file out of the raw_input? What I mean is say I have a code like this:

```
def file_make():
    name = raw_input("What do you want to name your file? \n")
    name_of_file = name + ".txt"
    file = open(name_of_file, "r")
    file.close()
    print name_of_file

file_make()
```

Could I take there input (EX: TEST) and then create a file called TEST.txt using the variable name? Or is this not possible? I tried searching for this question, but all of my searches pulled up how to take user input and make a text file out of it, which is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: And what's wrong with your code? - except the `"r"` mode that will throw an error if the file doesn't exist yet.

Comment: And that's exactly what it did. So should I remove the "r" and leave name_of_file in parentheses, alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have have your open method with write mode in order to write files, assuming the file doesn't exist.

Try

```
def file_make():
    name = raw_input("What do you want to name your file? \n")
    name_of_file = name + ".txt"
    file = open(name_of_file, "w")
    file.close()
    print name_of_file
file_make()
```

Comment: Awesome thankyou. Worked like a charm. Appreciate the help

Comment: Green check mark right? Sorry I dont use stack overflow that much. If so thats what I did. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You want to open the file in `'a'` mode (append), instead of read.